# Set default value of option dropdown

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Currently my dropdown is showing all posts from all users, but I want it to only show the user from user.id 1 named "Leanne Graham" by default, but can't seem to figure out how to get it to default to user id 1 instead of showing all posts from everyone by default. How can I tweak my code to make it default to the first option and not show all posts from all users by default?

usercomments.component.ts

```
<select class="form-control" (change)="reloadPosts({userId: u.value})" #u>
  <option value="">Select a user...</option>
  <option *ngFor="let user of users" value="{{user.id}}">

    {{user.name}}</option>

  </select>



<div class="container">


  <table class="table table-bordered">

    <tbody *ngFor="let post of _posts">
      <tr>
        <td>{{post.body}}</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>k</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

usercomments.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UserPostService} from './userpost.service';
import {UserService} from '../users/user.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-usercomments',
  templateUrl: './usercomments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usercomments.component.css'],
  providers: [UserPostService, UserService]
})
export class UsercommentsComponent implements OnInit {
private _posts;
users = [];
private selectedId;

postLoading;
private currentPost;
  constructor(private _userPostService: UserPostService, private _userService:UserService) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedId= this.users[1];
this._userService.getUsers()
.subscribe(users => this.users = users);
this.loadPosts();
  }
  loadPosts(filter?){

    this.postLoading = true;
    this._userPostService.getPosts(filter)
    .subscribe(res => {
    this._posts = res;

    })

  }
reloadPosts(filter){

this.currentPost = null;

this.loadPosts(filter);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngModel`

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedId" class="form-control"
```

and assign the id of the item you want to have selected to `selectedId`, then the select element will show this item as selected.

You can also use the `user` object instance instead of `user.id` but then you need to use `[ngValue]="user"` and ensure that `selected` in `[ngModel]="selected" gets one of the instance from`users` assigned.

Comment: When you say assign the id of the item you want selected, I'm thinking <select class="form-control" (change)="reloadPosts({userId: u.value})" #u [ngModel]="selectedId ==1">, but that isn't working so it must not be what you mean. How do you mean assign the id of the item in my example above?

Comment: I don't know how your user ids look like but I'd say `this.selectedId = this.users[3].id;`

Comment: I see what you're saying and I implemented like that in my .ts file, but the dropdown isn't populating still. Sorry i'm still new at this, but can you point out where I went wrong?

Comment: There are lots of similar questions. I won't have time today. Perhaps tomorrow.